# How I can get reference of same type of child component inside parent component

Tags: angular

For getting the child component reference we have option-

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent)
childComp: ChildComponent;
```

I wonder what if I have same child component twice or more, how I can get all same type child component in different different variable. For instance, inside my parent template I have-

```
<div>
  <child-selector></child-selector>
  <child-selector></child-selector>
</div>
```

How I can get reference of both same type child component inside parent component? Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ViewChildren

```
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent)
childComps: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
```

> *The children element which are located inside of its template of a component are called *view children *. On the other hand, **elements
>   which are used between the opening and closing tags of the host
>   element of a given component are called *content children **.

http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/

Comment: thnx for answer, when I am trying to get length of childComps using childComps.length it's giving undefined? How I can iterate and get each child selector reference?

Comment: you need hook to `AfterViewInit` lifecycle, after this event fired, you'll able to loop through your list. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterViewInit-class.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html